# Better experience / automate cleaning and building

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.8

Is there a better experience in Visual Studio 2015 with TypeScript? I currently have TypeScript 1.8 installed.

If I click clean, then build, everything works great.

However, if I build **without cleaning first**, my TS files do **not** get transpiled to JS. Old versions of my JS files persist and do not get updated. Is it possible to change this behavior so that my JS files get updated with every build command, or preferably on save?

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Is it preferred to use the CSPROJ TS settings?

My TypeScript files are included in the CSPROJ, and my JavaScript files are not.

Is there a better solution than alt-b + r (rebuild)?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a browser caching issue?

Comment: I've been reviewing the content of the JS files locally via notepad

Comment: Was your project created in VS2015, or is it older and you've migrated to VS2015? If it's an old project file it might not be set up correctly. Another point is that when using VS, tsconfig.json is ignored: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3983 "An easy way to think of this, is a project file (.csprox, .jsproj, .vbproj or .njsproj) and a tsconfig.json are mutually exclusive. if you have a project file the tsconfig is ignored. if you want to use a tsconfig file, do not use a project.". You can configure the project via a tab in the project properties.

Comment: Oh, my mistake ... apparently tsconfig.json is used in the ASP.Net vNext preview: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4161

Comment: If you use a tsconfig, the project file settings are ignored. Does anyone have it working better with the CSPROJ file settings instead of tsconfig? Do you want me to post the relevant parts of the CSPROJ file? I think that the project was created in vs2013 and now using 2015

Comment: I've found it better to have a separate console running tsc -w.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I had TypeScript 1.8 installed, my path environment variable was resolving tsc.exe out to TypeScript 1.6. Updated the path environment variable to point to 1.8, and then I was getting the experience I hoped for. When I save a TS file, it updates the JS file even if it already exists.

```
where tsc
```